# Run function in another file

Tags: react-native

I have this file to return address through geolocation:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

const __API_KEY__ = '&key=...';

export var address = '';

const getGeocode = () => {
  axios.get('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='+ this.state.latitude +','+ this.state.longitude + __API_KEY__)
.then(response => {
  console.log(response);
    this.setState({
        place: response.data.results[0].formatted_address
    })
    address = response.data.results[0].formatted_address
  }).catch((error) => {
    this.setState({ error: error.message })
  });
};

export const getGeolocation = () => (
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
    (position) => {
      this.setState({
        latitude: position.coords.latitude,
        longitude: position.coords.longitude,
        error: null,
      }, () => this.getGeocode());
    },
    address = position.coords.latitude,
    (error) => this.setState({ error: error.message }),
    { enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 20000 },
  )
);
```

I can return the **address** variable inside the other file where I need the address with:

```
import { Address } from './services/geolocation';
```

But what happens is that the variable comes empty because it does not execute the code that takes the geolocation, how can I make the variable return the address?

**[EDIT]**

I tried to follow the advice of turning into a function with the return of the address and I got in this code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

const __API_KEY__ = '&key=...';

function getGeocode( latitude, longitude ) {
  axios.get('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='+ latitude +','+ longitude + __API_KEY__)
  .then(response => {
    console.log(response);
      var address = response.data.results[0].formatted_address
    }).catch((error) => {
      this.setState({ error: error.message })
    });

  return address;
};

export function getGeolocation() {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
    (position) => {
      var address = getGeocode(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
    },
    (error) => this.setState({ error: error.message }),
    { enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 20000 },
  )
  console.log(address);

  return address;
};
```

And on the other I tried to import like this:

```
import { getGeolocation } from './services/geolocation';

const address = getGeolocation();
```

But I got this error back:

```
(0,_geolocation.getGeolocation) is not a function
```

Comment: you can modify the `getGeolocation()` function such that it returns the address and you can call `getGeolocation()` instead.

Comment: address != Address - is that a typo or how your actual code is?

Comment: @mckuok I tried but it is returning me an error

Comment: @MarkGuinn Sorry, my error typing here

Comment: I've edited above to demonstrate the changes and the error I'm getting

Comment: @Mate What error are you seeing?

Answer (score 0):

The easier way to do this is export a getAddress function instead of exporting the actual variable. So:

```
export function getAddress() { return address; }
```

(or the arrow function equivalent if you prefer that syntax).

Comment: I've edited above to demonstrate the changes and the error I'm getting

Comment: Do you also have a default export in the same module? Or are you showing us all the code here?